# Как получить список слов-"активаторов" для заданного слова?

Tags: python, строки, nlp

Допустим, есть адрес "ул. Октябрьская, д. 100"
Можно ли как-то получить список, в котором будут вроде тегов для данного адреса? То есть:

```
["улица октябрьская", "100", "октябрьская 100", "октябрьская, дом 100", "октябрьская 100"]
```

А для адреса `"ул. Ленина, 50"` результат был бы следующим:

```
["ленена 50", "ленина", "50", "улица ленина 50", "улица ленина дом 50"]
```

Уточнение: нужен не сплит, а чтобы "теги" получились с ошибками

Comment: ленина 50*, он Ленин а не Лена